# How to get raw html passed as jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery

Note: Answer given by SLacks requires the least code to get what I want  compared to answers in the duplicate questions. Accepting this.

I'm trying to do get the raw html that's passed in as the selector:

```
$('<div></div>')
```

I need just the html so `'<div></div>'`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the native `outerHTML` property:  `el[0].outerHTML`

**Note**: this is not quite "raw"; this is the HTML as parsed by the browser.

example of parsed output:

```
$("<div></div>")[0].outerHTML = "<div></div>";    
$("<div/>")[0].outerHTML = "<div></div>";
```

Comment: Doing this in the console gives an error $('<div></div>').outerHtml();

Comment: Note the `[0]` in the example: `$('<div></div>')[0].outerHtml();`

Comment: @User123 : `$('<div></div>')[0].outerHtml();`

Comment: property is not function... `$('<div></div>')[0].outerHTML`

Comment: $('<div></div>')[0].outerHtml(); <---- that also says outerHtml is not a function

Comment: Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/huyod8sz/

Comment: Sorry i didnt captialize the HTML ->, $("<div></div>")[0].outerHTML.. this works. Thanks SLaks!

Comment: on version 3.3.1 not aperar